# When is Ap's Num instance lawful?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, representable, typeclass-laws

Consider this type:

```hs
newtype Ap f a = Ap (f a)
instance (Applicative f, Num a) => Num (Ap f a) where
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  negate      = fmap negate
  fromInteger = pure . fromInteger
  abs         = fmap abs
  signum      = fmap signum
```

What needs to be true of `f` for that instance to be lawful? Clearly, just being a lawful `Applicative` isn't sufficient (e.g., `x + negate x` is different than `fromInteger 0` when `x` is `Ap Nothing`, even though `Maybe` is a lawful `Applicative`). My guess is that it's both necessary and sufficient for `f` to be a representable functor. I'm not sure how to go about proving this, though (or finding a counterexample if it's false).

For the sake of reference, here are the laws suggested by [the `Num` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num):

```
-- Associativity of (+)
(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)

-- Commutativity of (+)
x + y = y + x

-- fromInteger 0 is the additive identity
x + fromInteger 0 = x

-- negate gives the additive inverse
x + negate x = fromInteger 0

-- Associativity of (*)
(x * y) * z = x * (y * z)

-- fromInteger 1 is the multiplicative identity
x * fromInteger 1 = x
fromInteger 1 * x = x

-- Distributivity of (*) with respect to (+)
a * (b + c) = (a * b) + (a * c)
(b + c) * a = (b * a) + (c * a)
```

Comment: The Haskell Report has no laws for `Num`, so in principle it's always lawful. More realistically, one could instead take the [laws from the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) and try to simplify them for your specific case. (Commutativity looks quite strict for applicatives, IMO.)

Comment: @chi The laws from the docs are indeed the ones I meant.

Answer (score 6):

This structure is called an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field), which is a vector space equipped with a product. It is a fairly well known pattern to implement vector spaces as representable functors. This is what the [`linear` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) is all based around.

An algebra is trivially a [`ring`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) (by forgetting about scalars), and that's about the only thing everybody can agree on as to what the `Num` class actually describes. In that sense, yes, `Representable` is what's needed. Specifically, what you're exploiting is to substitute abstract vectors with their basis expansion, i.e. you're essentially reducing everything to

```
instance Num a => Num (r -> a) where
  fromInteger = const . fromInteger
  f + g = \e -> f e + g e
  f * g = \e -> f e * g e
  negate f = negate . f
  abs f = abs . f
  signum f = signum . f
```

which can then be used with `r ~ Rep f`, because the type `Rep f -> a` is isomorphic to `f a`.

I personally am not a fan of any of this. In particular the `Num` instances of `V2` etc. are a pain in the backside, because e.g. `1 :: V2 Double ≡ V2 1 1` doesn't make any sense whatsoever geometrically if you're dealing with e.g. diagrams, which are supposed to be rotation-agnostic. See, any finite-dimensional vector space *can* be realised with representable functors, but this entails picking an arbitrary basis. But this is a bit like picking an arbitrary character encoding for a text editor and then hard-baking it in a way that's fully exposed in the public interface. It's bad design. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you should.

Furthermore, many practically useful vector spaces can *not* sensibly be implemented with representable functors, or that implementation may be very impractical. I'm talking about sparse vectors here, or efficient unboxed and/or distributed storage, or (personal favourite) infinite-dimensional function spaces.

Therefore, what I recommend is to keep the `Num` class to things that are unequivocally *numbers*, and call everything else explicitly by what you actually want. My [free-vector-spaces](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-vector-spaces) and [linearmap-category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category) packages attempt to do that in a principled and powerful way, building upon the simple and safe classes from [vector-space](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space).

Answer (score 3):

> What needs to be true of `f` for that instance to be lawful?

To sketch an argument, we can begin by focusing on the effects monoid (`Ap f ()`, if you will) which lies under the applicative. For left distributivity to hold, we need the effects monoid to be left self-distributive (that is, `u <> (v <> w) = (u <> v) <> (u <> w)`), and analogously for right distributivity. Furthermore, if a monoid is both left self-distributive and right self-distributive [it must be both commutative and idempotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868401/380202). That is a hefty restriction already, though it is not enough to rule out `Maybe` (which is an idempotent, commutative applicative). That being so, it makes sense to use your hint and look at the additive inverse law:

```
x + negate x = fromInteger 0
-- Substitute the instance implementations:
liftA2 (+) x (negate <$> x) = pure (fromInteger 0)
-- (&*&) = liftA2 (,)
(\(a, b) -> a + negate b) <$> (x &*& x) = pure (fromInteger 0)
```

In particular, using `(() <$)` on both sides gives us:

```
() <$ (x &*& x) = pure ()
```

Going back to the effects monoid point of view, that amounts to `u <> u = mempty`. Since we had established earlier that the effects monoid must be idempotent, `u <> u = u`. Therefore, `u = mempty`; that is, there is just one possible `Ap f ()`.

As for the other laws, identity and associativity should follow from the applicative laws, while commutativity of `(+)` presumably requires `f` to be a commutative applicative...

```
liftA2 g u v = liftA2 (flip g) v u
```

... which is a bit stronger than merely requiring the commutativity of `Ap f ()` that I mentioned before (see [`Select`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Select.html) for an illustration of that).

For the `Num (Ap f a)` instance to be lawful, therefore, it seems we need at least that `f` is a commutative applicative, and that there is just one `f ()` value. While the argument isn't quite watertight just yet, those requirements are indeed strongly reminiscent of representable functors.